# Making pairs of a string and an element in a list

Tags: python, string, zip

I have a single string that I would like to make pair with each element in a list.

```
str = "era"
list = ["we", "st"]
```

With the code:

```
zip(str, list)
```

I obtain

```
 [('e', 'we'), ('r', 'st')]
```

What I would like to achieve is a list of tuples of the pairs:

```
 [('era', 'we'), ('era', 'st')]
```

Is there a simple way to get around with the split of the string? Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

How about a list comprehension?

```
str = 'era'
list = ['we', 'st']
packed = [(str,str2) for str2 in list]
```

Comment: Dang it. You beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

ss = "era"
lst = ["we", "st"]
print list(itertools.product([ss], lst))
```

Avoid using keyword as variables, such as **list**.

Comment: This is kind of overkill I think, but I tested it with a lst of length 1000, and your answer is roughly 5 times faster than my list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd offer an alternative to @*jphollowed*'s simple and concise answer.

```
s = "era"
l = ["we", "st"]
print([tuple(i.split(',')) for i in map(lambda x: x+','+s, l)])
```

Comment: Much less readable, imo. Don't know what it offers in speed, though

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree, you just beat everyone to the most pythonic answer aha, so thought I'd just offer an alternative method for curiosity's sake.

Comment: hmm, I can't get it to work; `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`

Comment: Am I dumb here? `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')` I'm using a array of 1000 floats as `lst`, so perhaps this method only works if both tuple elements are the same type

Comment: This is meant for string concatenation, as the `+` is used on string arguments. Try `lambda x: str(x)+','+s`. Should work with your list of floats.

Comment: Sorry about that. It seems that @citaret 's answer is ~5x faster than mine, and mine is ~2x faster than yours. huh.